# How chsh is implemented in linux?

Tags: linux, security, unix

The `chsh` program is used to change a user's login shell by modifying `/etc/passwd` file.  Anyone can issue this command, but ordinary users must not be able to change each other's default shell.

How does a program such as `chsh` allow a user to change their own shell but not that of a different user?  Are there specific system or library calls that need to be used?

Comment: @TobySpeight: I disagree. I think the OP is asking how `chsh` implements its security, not how the tool is to be used. And that is a programming question.

Comment: @rodrigo - I've edited the question a little and retracted my close-vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually easy. `chsh` is a set-uid program:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/chsh
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root ... /usr/bin/chsh
   ^
   +--- see the 's'!
```

So the program is run with the effective UID of root.

Now, how does it know which user is calling it? Because set set-uid changes the **effective** UID, but not the **real** UID. By comparing the real UID with the `passwd` line you want to change, it can check whether you are allowed to do that.

Remember that a normal user can only change its own line, while the real root is allowed to change anyone's.

For more details, see the man pages for `getuid`, `geteuid` and the other functions linked there.

Comment: I can understand the concept from your answer. Can you please share the C code of chsh?

Comment: The Linux version of chsh is [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/login-utils/chsh.c#n287). I've highlighted the line I think you are interested in.

Comment: @Kaustav - [Debian's implementation of `chsh`](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-shadow/shadow.git/tree/src/chsh.c#n263) was pretty easy to find and read, for example.  I doubt that other implementations are any more complex.